# How to use UIInterfaceOrientationMask

Tags: iphone, swift, uiinterfaceorientation, ios8

I've been trying to use UIInterfaceOrientationMask in my Swift code. In Objective-C, I would use it as an enum, and when I needed to use, for example, the portrait mask, I would simply use `UIPortraitOrientationMask` in my code, like so:

```
NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to do with the documentation, and I haven't been able to find anything about a "Raw Option Set" anywhere in the tutorial book or the documentation.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the '.' format to set / check for a value, like so:

```
import UIKit
var orientation : UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .Portrait
orientation = .All
if (orientation == .Landscape) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: It should also be noted that if you need to get the UInt value of a UIInterfaceOrientationMask, use `orientation.value`, rather than just using `orientation`, as you would in Objective-C

Answer (score 7):

As of Xcode 7, Swift Version 2.0:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask { return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait }
```

Original obsolete answer below:

As of Xcode 6.2 or 6.3, or Swift version 1.2:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int { return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue) }
```

`supportedInterfaceOrientations` is defined to return an Int, but `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` is an enumeration. So, use the `rawValue` property of the enumeration to find its raw value, which gives a UInt. The Int() function takes the UInt as an input and returns an Int.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the same value in Swift like this: `UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait`